# Deleting orphan blobs in appengine blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, blobstore

I deleted a large number of objects from the datastore that I din't 
require (around 7000 of them). 
Each of those objects had a blob associated with it, referenced by a 
String (blob key). 
As you might have guessed by now, I forgot to delete those blobs. 
Now I don't have any reference to them, but I want to delete them. 
I can't seem to find a way to do that. 
Any help will be appreciated.
**UPDATE**
Found the solution.

```
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
List<BlobInfo> blobsToCheck = new LinkedList<BlobInfo>(); 
Iterator<BlobInfo> iterator = null;
if(afterBlobKey == null){
    iterator = new BlobInfoFactory().queryBlobInfos();
}else{
    iterator = new BlobInfoFactory().queryBlobInfosAfter(new BlobKey(afterBlobKey));
}

while(iterator.hasNext()){

    blobsToCheck.add(iterator.next());

}

//Check those blobs if they have reference in datastore
//Delete using blobstoreService.delete(blobKey);
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to find and delete orphaned blobs in the app engine blobstore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935980/is-it-possible-to-find-and-delete-orphaned-blobs-in-the-app-engine-blobstore)

Comment: @systempuntoout thanks, although I was looking for a Java solution, the question you have linked to, helped in solving my problem.

Comment: glad it helped. You could post your own Java solution here as an answer marking it as accepted; it would helpful for other people.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**UPDATE** Found the solution, BlobInfoFactory().queryBlobInfos() is what I was looking for.

```
    DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
    List<BlobInfo> blobsToCheck = new LinkedList<BlobInfo>(); 
    Iterator<BlobInfo> iterator = null;
    if(afterBlobKey == null){
        iterator = new BlobInfoFactory().queryBlobInfos();
    }else{
        iterator = new BlobInfoFactory().queryBlobInfosAfter(new BlobKey(afterBlobKey));
    }

    while(iterator.hasNext()){

        blobsToCheck.add(iterator.next());

    }

    //Check those blobs if they have reference in datastore
    //Delete using blobstoreService.delete(blobKey);
```