# delete entity with blobkey without deleting corresponding blob

Tags: python, google-cloud-datastore, blob, blobstore

Lets say I have some entities in the datastore that have blobkey properties that point to on particular blob in the blobstore. Now If i delete those entities, what happens to the blob in the blobstore now that nothing points to it? Does it just stay in the blobstore forever? would it be possible to delete it somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deleting orphan blobs in appengine blobstore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362013/deleting-orphan-blobs-in-appengine-blobstore)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blob will remain until you explicitly [delete](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/functions) it.

You should still be able to retrieve the blob information using [the blobinfo class](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass).