# App Engine: Delete Google Cloud Storage Entry, Appears Orphaned in Blob Viewer

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am storing objects in Google Cloud Storage through the Blobstore API.
When it comes time to delete an object, I use:

```
key = blobstore.create_gs_key(gs_object_name)
blobstore.delete(key)
```

This deletes the object from Google Cloud Storage, but when I look at Blob Viewer in the App Engine Dashboard site it appears that entries still exist in the Blobstore for each of the objects. When I click on any of the orphans the preview section of the page shows: "Error: Server Error"

Should I delete them using another method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems when you are using they key from create_gs_key for deleting, the blob in the cloud storage and its corresponding fileinfo object are getting deleted , but not the blobinfo stored in the datastore. What you view in blob viewer in app engine is this blobinfo entity which has details like size, filetype, etc. When you click on any of these entries, it should show the corresponding blob and since its already deleted, you must be seeing the error message.

This earlier post explains [how to delete orphan blobinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935980/is-it-possible-to-find-and-delete-orphaned-blobs-in-the-app-engine-blobstore).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What you state may well be the case, but I don't think that post on how to delete orphan blobinfo is a solution. If I read it right, I think in that case someone was deleting references to blobs and needed to find blobs that had no references, and in this case I am deleting some underlying blob data, and need to find which blobs have no data. Optimally, I think it would be best of the blobstore.delete(blobstore.create_gs_key(gs_name)) would delete the blobstore entry automatically - might be a feature request/bug.