# how to delete orphaned blob in google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, blobstore

I have been following instructions on this site - [Is it possible to find and delete orphaned blobs in the app engine blobstore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2935980/is-it-possible-to-find-and-delete-orphaned-blobs-in-the-app-engine-blobstore) - on how to delete orphaned blobs, but I keep getting an error.

```
from google.appengine.ext.blobstore import BlobInfo

#Here is where I store my blobKeys
class Content(ndb.Model):
  blobKey = ndb.BlobKeyProperty(required=False)

#Here is what I've been trying to follow
class Refresh(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
  def get(self):
  blobs = BlobInfo.all().fetch(500)
  for blob in blobs:
    if not Content.all().filter("blob_ref =", blob.key()).count(1): #ERROR
      blob.delete()
```

I keep getting the error `AttributeError: type object 'Content' has no attribute 'all'`

The poster mentions that "If your BlobReferenceProperty field is indexed, then yes, it's quite possible." Could it be an issue that I'm using ndb.BlobKeyProperty rather than BlobReferenceProperty? Thanks, for reading.

**Update**
Refer to [Expected BlobKey but instead I get a BlobInfo object - How to get BlobKey from BlobInfo object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045315/expected-blobkey-but-instead-i-get-a-blobinfo-object-how-to-get-blobkey-from-b) to see the solution

Comment: Google is moving away from the blobstore. The Files api is already deprecated. You can use Google cloud storage which does not allow blob versions with the same filename.

Comment: Thanks voscausa, I have a question though. When google says "files api is deprecated" does that mean you will no longer be able to upload pictures to blobstore anymore? According to https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/ it looks like `blob_info = upload_files[0]` will be fine.

Comment: In other words, I haven't used `from google.appengine.api import files` in my code at all

Comment: Yes, you can still upload files. You only need the Files API if an application writes data to the blobstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing db and ndb apis

To query with ndb you use the `query` method

In your case

`blobs = BlobInfo.query().fetch(500)`

But this is not really correct.  You should rewrite it to

```
for blob in BlobInfo.query(options=QueryOptions(batchsize=200))
   # do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm reading through https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass#BlobInfo_all and still can't get your code to work. I'm trying to `self.response.out.write(str(blobs))` just to see what's coming out but nothing shows up. I also get the error `AttributeError: type object 'BlobInfo' has no attribute 'query'` when I try to use `blobs = BlobInfo.query().fetch(500)`

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized what you meant. BlobInfo is MyModel. Thanks

Comment: I just transposed your code, and corrected it for ndb, I didn't bother going into to it too deep ;-)