# Expected BlobKey but instead I get a BlobInfo object - How to get BlobKey from BlobInfo object?

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, blobstore

What's the best way to get a BlobKey from a BlobInfo object?

```
def get(self):
  blobs = BlobInfo.all()
  #something is missing here
  for blob in blobs:
    if not Content.query().filter(ndb.BlobKeyProperty("blobKey") == blob.key).count(1): #ERROR
      blob.delete()                                                    ^
                                              **how do you do make this a normal BlobKey?**



#Error
BadValueError: Expected BlobKey, got <bound method BlobInfo.key of
<google.appengine.ext.blobstore.blobstore.BlobInfo object at 0x048B87D0>>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Docs: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/blobinfoclass#BlobInfo_key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BlobInfo.key is a method, not a property, so call it: `blob.key()`

Comment: THANKS!!! I can't believe those two parenthesis caused me so much trouble. You're awesome